# Removing an intercept in Cypress

Tags: cypress, integration-testing, cypress-intercept

I have an intercept that serves up a stubbed JSON response like this:

```javascript
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v1/myroute/*', { fixture: 'myData.json' }).as('myAlias')
```

Is there a way I can remove this intercept halfway through a test somehow? I was hoping to delete the alias so the xhr request doesn't get intercepted at all.

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured this one out. Simply do this:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v1/myroute/*', (req) => {
  req.continue()
});
```

Comment: How did you implement it? It does not change the result for me:
`cy.intercept('/api/console/profile', (req) => {
            req.continue((res) => {
                res.send({
                    result: updatedPhoneNumberProfile,
                });
            });
        })`

Comment: You can later remove it by intercepting the same route with null as the handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [RouteMatcher](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Icon-nameangle-right--routeMatcher-RouteMatcher)'s **times** option like this:

```
cy.intercept({
  method: 'GET',
  pathname: '/api/v1/myroute/*'
  times: 1
}, { fixture: 'myData.json' }).as('myAlias')
```

so when it is called a second time it won't be intercepted